# Consolidate all files to one server

Tags: awstats

I want to setup awstats to 10 server , each of these run the schedule job to export the awstats042015.mydomain.txt , then scp these files to a centralized server , so that I can use one check to control all logs , I can use the following URL to check all statistics of all 10 server , rather than have 10 different URL , each URL for each server ?

would advise what can I do ? thanks

```
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain1
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain2
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain3
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain4
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain5
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain6
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain7
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain8
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain9
http://mydomain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain10
```

Comment: Are you asking how in general you can move files between servers, or is this unique to AwStats? If you know in general how to move files between servers, just create a cron job to transfer them in on regular intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do on that way. 
On each server you use a schedule job to ceate awstatsMMYYYY.mydomain.txt  file.

cmd: perl awstats.pl -update -config=mydomain

Each domain require a awstats.mydomain.conf file.

Then scp all awstatsMMYYYY.mydomain.txt to center server for analyzation.